# android list background with seperate list item background overlap

Tags: android, listview, selector

I've created a list view and set up a selector for it so that it has a background on it.  I did the same for the list item elements in it.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67419/list.png

The list itself is grey and has the dark grey border on the right side. When a list item is activated, I have the background of the list item changed to white via its own selector.  However, I can't seem to get the white background to take up the entire space of the listview and it leaves a few pixels to the right (just enough to only show the border from the background). Is there a way to make it extend all of the way?  To the right of the list is a white fragment so I want the white from the list item to connect to the white of the fragment.

my list_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/grey" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

and my list_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rightborder" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `android:constantSize="true"` in the selector attributes?

Comment: It doesn't look like that changed anything. I tried attaching it to the list item, the list, and both.